# back press with bottomNavigationView

Tags: android, bottomnavigationview

In my app I use bottomNavigationView with jetpack navigation
Look at the picture
[image]

I have 2 pages
When I click to second page, then click back press, I return to first fragment, but I want to close app
some code

```
private fun initView() {
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar)
    bottomNavigationView = findViewById(R.id.bottom_navigation)
    val navHostFragment = supportFragmentManager
        .findFragmentById(R.id.nav_host_fragment) as NavHostFragment
    navController = navHostFragment.navController

    navController?.apply {
        appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(setOf(
            R.id.action_home,
            R.id.action_favorite
        ))
        appBarConfiguration?.let {
            setupActionBarWithNavController(this, it)
        }
        bottomNavigationView?.let {
            NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(it, this)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One way of doing it is if you want custom behaviour from the back button, you will need to override [onBackPressed()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#onBackPressed()) in your activity

Answer (score 0):

```
override fun onBackPressed() {
    if (R.id.action_favorite == navController?.currentDestination?.id) {
        finish()
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed()
    }
}
```